# Swagger-php on Yii2 ActiveController

Tags: rest, activerecord, yii2, swagger, swagger-php

I have a REST api running in my yii2 app.
I extend my api model from my AR model and use the `fields()` function to define the api response fields.

```
/**
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *   type="object"
 * )
 */    
class Person extends \common\models\Person implements Linkable {

    public function fields() {
        return ['id',
                'name',
                'first-name' => 'first_name'
        ];
    }    

    public function getLinks() {
        return [
                Link::REL_SELF  => Url::to(['person/view', 'id' => $this->id], true),
        ];
    }
```

My activecontroller is the easiest implementation

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

/**
 * @SWG\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
 */
class PersonController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Person';

}
```

So far, everything works. Then I wanted to add Swagger-php to document my API:
I use https://packagist.org/packages/light/yii2-swagger. The configuration works and I have my swagger-ui page/json.

The next step is to start adding documentation... But in all the Swagger-php examples or on https://github.com/lichunqiang/yii2-swagger-demo, the annotations are on the modelfields and the controller methods.
The problem is that those are not explicitly in the code because of ActiveRecord and the `fields()` function.

Is there are way to combine swagger-php and ActiveController?

Comment: There is no way to extract informations from your controller to be understood by swagger-php right now. But you can be the 1st one to make it possible.
https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle is a project that is able to read annotations from both nelmio (@ApiDoc), swagger-php (@SWG) and JMS (@JMSSerializer) projects to extract an API definition and build a documentation about it.